# how to keep visited urls and maintain the job queue when writing a crawler

Tags: redis, web-crawler

I'm writing a crawler. I keep the visited urls in redis set,and maintain the job queue using redis list. As data grows,memory is used up, my memory is 4G. How to maintain these without redis? I have no idea,if I store these in files,they also need to be in memory.

If I use a mysql to store that,I think it maybe much slower than redis.

I have 5 machines with 4G memory,if anyone has some material to set up a redis cluster,it also helps a lot. I have some material to set up a cluster to be failover ,but what I need is to set a load balanced cluster.

thx

Answer (score 2):

If you are just doing the basic operations of adding/removing from sets and lists, take a look at [twemproxy/nutcracker](https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy). With it you can use all of the nodes.

Regarding your usage pattern itself, are you removing or expiring jobs and URLs? How much repetition is there in the system? For example, are you repeatedly crawling the same URLs? If so, perhaps you only need a mapping of URLs to their last crawl time, and instead of a job queue you pull URLs that are new or outside a given window since their last run.

Without the details on how your crawler actually runs or interacts with Redis, that is about what I can offer. If memory grows continually, it likely means you aren't cleaning up the DB.